# .vdproj parser wanted

Tags: c#, parsing, vdproj

I'm looking for some c# sample code or a tool that could parse .vdproj file (Visual 2010 Studio Setup and Deployment Project).

Comment: what information were you looking to parse out of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest using C# and LINQ to parse this file. Let's go with [this vdproj sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAwn.png). Unfortunately it's not XML based, but rather it looks *similar to JSON*, but not exactly.

[image]

Suggest to iterate through the lines. Determine where you are based on the number of tabs seen, and the line number of the *section heading* you want to parse out.

```
  string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\foo.vdproj");

  // iterate, and determine where the Configuration heading is....
  if (line == "\t\"Configurations\"")
```

My sample code is too large to paste here, so please see the code at http://pastebin.com/DAiTCUtD

The complexity goes as far as how much data you need to extract from the file.

Hope this helps. Sounds like you were looking for a prebuilt tool, but perhaps this code gets you started in parsing .vdproj files.

Comment: Hmmm.. I was thinking of using Regex.Split() thing. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a simple console application that converts a VDPROJ file to/from an XML structure. This made it much simpler to do things like set the add/remove programs icon in our build process.

https://github.com/dump247/VDProjectXml

Answer (score 0):

Got something [here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2006/12/26/working-offline-with-tfs.aspx). hope that this is it

Upd: D'oh! It has bunch of tools like VCProjectBindingParser.cs and VBProjectBindingParser.cs and nothing for .vdproj. I don't know, probably I'm gonna need to build my own parser.

Ahhh (heavily sighing) Just wanted to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield can convert VDPROJ to ISM.   That makes it an MSI database that could then be queried or Darked into WiX.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_ = join('', <>);

s/[=](.+)/:$1,/g;
s/[{]/: {/sg;
s/}/},/g;

s/[,](?:\s+)?[}]/}/sg;
s/[,](?:\s+)?$//s;

print "{$_}";
```

^-- this perl snippet converts [my] vdproj to json.